# How to rewrite rails group_by class method as scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, scope, refactoring

I would like to rewrite my class method as a scope.

```
class Team

 def self.grouped
   self.all.group_by { |e| e.type }.map { |k, v| { k => v.group_by { |e| e.sub_type } } }
 end

end
```

How would I write as a scope?

```
class Team

 #  scope :grouped ??

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write this as a scope. Scopes in Rails act on `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects and are supposed to generate `SQL` queries that run against the database.

But the `group_by` method is called on the `array` after the data was received from the database.

You will always have to load the data from the database first, before you can group it with `group_by`.

You could write your own `nested_group_by` method on Array:

```
class Array
  def nested_grouped_by(group_1, group_2)
    group_by { |e| e.send(group_1) }.
      map { |k, v| { k => v.group_by { |e| e.send(group_2) } } }
  end
end
```

That could be used like this:

```
Team.all.nested_grouped_by(:type, :subtype)
```

Note the `all` that force the scope to actually load the data from the database and returns an array.