# Rails sort scope by custom method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a scope which does the fetching

```
    scope :between, -> (start, endd) {
           where(:start_time => start..endd}
    }
```

and a custom method

```
 def time_of_day 
   Helper.time_of_day(start_time || est_start_time  )
 end
```

I want to be able to group the results by a custom method

```
Class.between
Class.between.time_of_start
```

So far, I've tried

```
def self.custom_sort
   self.group_by { |a| a.time_of_start }
end
```

But I get

> NoMethodError: undefined method `by_time' for Instance::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000005537e60>

I know I can do things like

```
Class.between.group_by { |a| a.time_of_start}
```

But I want to define a custom 'scope'

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared more actual code. Your abstraction has made a somewhat nonsensical hypothetical.

Comment: I added a bit of code

Comment: Try `self.all.group_by { |a| a.time_of_start }`

Comment: It worked, do you want to make it an answer?

Comment: Ok, wait..i will put it as an answer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `.all` like:

```
self.all.group_by { |a| a.time_of_start }
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36390251/6548745)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
scope :between, -> {
              where(...)
  }


scope :grouped, -> {
              group_by { |a| a.custom_method }
  }

private

def custom_method 
   #some manipulation
end
```

The you can call:

```
Class.between.grouped
```

Comment: But I want to have 2 scopes, with and without group by, doing this, I need to duplicate the 'where' code

Comment: I get 'NoMethodError: undefined method `group_by' for #<Class:0x00000005f44b88>' whats the correct sintax for group?

Comment: @Gaston .group_by is an Enumerable and not an ActiveRecord method, look into .group